# Spring Boot SQLite run compile error

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, spring-boot

I have a problem in the compilation of a jar spring boot, the project works in eclipse, but not when it is compiled opening it with the command java -jar etc.

The database is SQLite and Spring Boot 2.0.0M

error stack:

```
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        2018-08-11 15:20:24.596  INFO 28318 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

properties.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource: 
    driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
    url: jdbc:sqlite:com.geoscanner.util.bounds.db
    username: 
    password: 
jpa: 
   database-platform: com.geoscanner.util.SQLiteDialect
   hibernate.ddl-auto: none
   generate-ddl: false
   show-sql: true
mvc:
  dispatch-options-request: true
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.geoscanner</groupId>
<artifactId>GeoScanner</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>GeoScanner</name>
<description>GeoScanner</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zsoltfabok/sqlite-dialect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for watching and responding, as always.

Comment: Can you please share the whole project. It is working fine with me

Comment: @Dinesh here -> https://github.com/Gervalos/GeoScanner